# It shows nil in the database, can this solve the main issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If a seller sells something, I'm unable to show the user who bought it. With a Sale, Product, and User models

```
<% @sales.each do |sale| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= link_to sale.product.title, pickup_path(sale.guid) %></td>
    <td><%= time_ago_in_words(sale.created_at) %> ago</td>
    <td><%= sale.seller_email %></td>
    <td><%= sale.amount %></td>
```

If I go ahead and change it to `<%= sale.buyer_email %>`, it just shows me the current user and what THEY just bought rather than WHO bought their item. This is what I get after checking the console, the `seller_email` is nil and the amount is nil for the last sale. How do I fix this so that the seller can see who go their item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the model structure should be changed to create a correct architecture.

You have User, Product and Sale models. So the Association should be like the following.

```
class User
  has_many :products
  has_many :sales
  has_many :customers, :through => :sales
end

class Product
  has_many :sales
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :buyers, :through => :sales
  has_many :sellers, :through => :sales
end

class Sale
  belongs_to :seller, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Then you can access all the buyers & seller of the product by following line of codes.

```
product.buyers
product.sellers
```

Comment: I dont a customer model and when I try implementing this I get this, "<User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa21cf114c0>"

Comment: I don't have a customer model and when I try implementing this I get this, after imputing  <%= sale.product.sellers %><User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa21cf114c0>

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your `current_user` in the `Transaction` controller is nil.

I can see you are missing the `before_action :authenticate_user!` in the `Transaction Controller`.

So you could check this by using a debug gem like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) , try to add `binding.pry` just before `product.sales.create!(buyer_email: current_user.email)` and see if the `current_user` has a value

HTH

Comment: Is it because of the model its not being saved?